# Checkbox behaving weird when variables are local

Tags: dynamic, bugs, scoping

I have a `DynamicModule` in which I need a checkbox with a `Max` in the dynamic part:

```
Checkbox[Dynamic[... Max ...]]
```

After removing everything else from the `DynamicModule`, it still behaves badly: (whether `q[[1, 1]]` is false or true, the checkbox shows a big square, although `q[[1,1]]` doesnt have a bad value):

```
DynamicModule[{s = 1, q = {{False}}},
  {Checkbox[Dynamic[q[[1, 2 - Max[s, 0]]]]], Dynamic[q[[1, 2 - Max[s, 0]]]]}]
```

If variables aren't local, it behaves well:

```
s = 1; q = {{False}};
Checkbox[Dynamic[q[[1, 2 - Max[s, 0]]]]]
Dynamic[q[[1, 2 - Max[s, 0]]]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be a front-end bug involving the evaluation of arrays and built-in functions within a `DynamicBox`.  The original example can be made to work by defining `max = Max;` and using the user function `max` in place of the built-in function`Max`:

```
max = Max;
DynamicModule[{s = 1, q = {{False}}},
  {Checkbox[Dynamic[q[[1, 2 - max[s, 0]]]]], Dynamic[q[[1, 2 - max[s, 0]]]]}]
```

Here is a screenshot showing the original example and the work-around:

[image: screenshot]

The work-around also responds to mouse clicks properly.

An alternative that does not rely on the global function definition `max` is to "hide" the built-in function `Max` by writing `Max[##]&` instead:

```
DynamicModule[{s = 1, q = {{False}}},
  {Checkbox[Dynamic[q[[1, 2 - Max[##]&[s, 0]]]]], Dynamic[q[[1, 2 - Max[##]&[s, 0]]]]}]
```

---

**Analysis**

As evidence for the claim that this is a bug, consider the following evaluations (tested under *Mathematica* versions 7, 8 and 9 on Windows, 64-bit).  The problem can be exhibited by direct generation of `DynamicBox` structures, taking out of the picture all of the complex "double-evaluation" and "demodularization" processing done by `DynamicModule`.

Here is a trivial use of `DynamicBox`:

```
RawBoxes @ DynamicModuleBox[{q = {0}}, DynamicBox @ ToBoxes @ q[[1]]]
(* 0 *)
```

The result is a cell that displays the value `0`.  However, observe the puzzling behaviour that occurs when `q[[1]]` is changed to `q[[Max@1]]`:

```
RawBoxes @ DynamicModuleBox[{q={0}}, DynamicBox @ ToBoxes @ q[[Max@1]]]
(* List *)
```

For some reason, the result shows `List` instead of `0`.  Some other built-in functions, such as `Sqrt` and `Sin` fail in similar fashion:

```
RawBoxes @ DynamicModuleBox[{q={0}}, DynamicBox @ ToBoxes @ q[[Sqrt@1]]]
(* List *)

RawBoxes @ DynamicModuleBox[{q={0}}, DynamicBox @ ToBoxes @ q[[Sin@1]]]
(* List *)
```

But other functions, such as `Abs`, `Plus` and `Identity` do not:

```
RawBoxes @ DynamicModuleBox[{q={0}}, DynamicBox @ ToBoxes @ q[[Abs@1]]]
(* 0 *)

RawBoxes @ DynamicModuleBox[{q={0}}, DynamicBox @ ToBoxes @ q[[Plus@1]]]
(* 0 *)

RawBoxes @ DynamicModuleBox[{q={0}}, DynamicBox @ ToBoxes @ q[[Identity@1]]]
(* 0 *)
```

User-defined functions behave properly, even when they are implemented in terms of built-in functions that do not:

```
max = Max;
RawBoxes @ DynamicModuleBox[{q={0}}, DynamicBox @ ToBoxes @ q[[max@1]]]
(* 0 *)

RawBoxes @ DynamicModuleBox[{q={0}}, DynamicBox @ ToBoxes @ q[[Max[##]&@1]]]
(* 0 *)
```

It would appear that some built-in kernel evaluation rules or array reference optimizations are not compatible with dynamic boxes.  Perhaps the front-end rendering code is failing to take such cases into account.

Comment: I have sent a bug report to WRI.

Comment: This bug still persists in V10 (on OS X 10.9.4 at least)

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea, I hope this work-around will help you until someone competent posts an answer.

```
DynamicModule[{s, q, z},
 {     
   Checkbox[ Dynamic[z, (z = q[[1, 2 - Max[s, 0]]] = #) &]],
   Dynamic[q[[1, 2 - Max[s, 0]]]]
 },
 Initialization :> (s = 1; q = {{z = False}};)]
```